# COUNTIFS does not seem to count blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [COUNTIFS does not seem to count blank cells](https://superuser.com/questions/333946/countifs-does-not-seem-to-count-blank-cells)

I am trying to build a COUNTIF statement in Excel 2010 using a total of 4 sets of criteria. I would ideally like it to look something like this:

```
COUNTIFS(range1,value in a1,range2,value in b1,range3,value in c1,range4,value in d1)
```

This works fine if there are actual values in cells A1-D1. however, if one of those cells is blank, I don't get the number back that I would expect. (I am testing this by autofiltering using the criteria I'm setting in A1-D1). What DOES seem to be happening is that if C1 is blank, then the COUNTIFS returns a count of all rows where C1 is not blank.

Is there a way to set a default so that if there is no value in A1-D1, COUNTIFS includes everything?

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria argument is a reference to an empty cell, the COUNTIFS function treats the empty cell as a 0 value.

If you are trying to match empty cells, put a single quote ' in the criteria cell (*displays* as a blank cell)  This will match actual blank cells